# Why does running "pkill -f <anything>" over ssh fail only when branching on its result?

Tags: bash, ssh, pkill

Found an interesting interaction between `pkill` and `ssh`.  Documenting it here for posterity:

```
$ ssh user@remote 'false'; echo $?                                                              
1

$ ssh user@remote 'false || echo "failed"'; echo $?
failed
0

$ ssh user@remote 'pkill -f "fake_process"'; echo $?                                               
1

$ ssh user@remote 'pkill -f "fake_process" || echo "failed"'; echo $?
255
```

It seems like example #4 should have the same output as #2; both `false` and `pkill -f "fake_process"` exit with code `1` and have no output.  However, #4 will always exit with code `255`, even if the remote command explicitly calls `exit 0`.  The docs for `ssh` state that code `255` just means "an error occurred" (super helpful).

Replacing the `pkill` command with `(exit 1)`, `ls fake_file`, `kill <non-existent PID>`, etc. all work as expected.  Additionally, when running locally (not through `ssh`), these match as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `pkill` is killing itself.  Or rather, it is killing the shell that owns it.

First of all, it appears that `ssh` uses the remote user's shell to execute certain "complicated" commands:

```
$ ssh user@remote 'ps -F --pid $$'
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user      9531  9526  0 11862  1616   6 14:36 ?        00:00:00 ps -F --pid 9531

$ ssh user@remote 'ps -F --pid $$ && echo hi'
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user      9581  9577  0 28316  1588   5 14:36 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ps -F --pid $$ && echo hi
hi
```

Second, it appears that `pkill -f` normally knows not to kill itself (otherwise all `pkill -f` commands would suicide).  But if run from a subshell, that logic fails:

```
$ pkill -f fake_process; echo $?
1

$ sh -c 'pkill -f fake_process'; echo $?
[1]    14031 terminated  sh -c 'pkill -f fake_process'
143
```

In my case, to fix this I just re-worked some of the code around my `ssh`/`pkill` so that I could avoid having a "complicated" remote command.  Theoretically I think you could also do something like `pgrep -f <cmd> | grep -v $$ | xargs kill`.

Comment: ssh uses the remote shell to execute **all** commands. There exists no case when the remote shell is not used (though there are some cases where the shell may just `exec` another command and not remain in memory; you've spotted one of those, but that `ps` command is *first* a `$SHELL -c 'ps ...'` command, and just gets replaced with a `ps` process by bash after it determines that there's nothing it needs to do after `ps` finishes executing, and thus can `exec` with no prior `fork`).

Comment: ...whether a given shell implements that optimization is implementation-defined, so one doesn't want to depend on whether it exists.